# Unpack javascript contents with php

Tags: javascript, php

iknow there is online sites to unpack compressed javascript content , but i want to know how to do it with php because i want to unpack it and use preg_match to get specified data

here is exemple : `eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=String;if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[c]=k[c]||c;k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('(0(){4 1="5 6 7 8";0 2(3){9(3)}2(1)})();',10,10,'function|b|something|a|var|some|sample|packed|code|alert'.split('|'),0,{}))`

Comment: do you want to unpack this code? this is a javascript code? the packer is made by [dean edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/)

Comment: Ghost iknow ; but i want code php to unpack it , thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to evaluate and parse the functions one by one and add the whitespace and formatting to it.

Comment: There is no automated way of doing this. Read the text, if you encounter a command and parenthesis than you can apply the correct formatting to the output text.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a unpacker class for that purpose, but already answered the question on another stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982151/js-unpacker-via-php-functionp-a-c-k-e-r) where you'll find the link to the project files on Git.